# rails 3; activerecord; where; NOT EQUAL condition comparison between two columns in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there some way of comparing two columns in a database using *where*?

Say, I have two columns for **user** that tells:

1. city_of_birth
2. favourite_city

And I would like a list of users that have favourite_city that is different from city_of_birth.

I was hoping something like this would work.

```
@users = User.where(
  :city_of_birth != :favourite_city
).all
```

Running this results in

```
undefined method `where' for nil:NilClass
```

There are similar questions asked about using conditional statements for *where*, but none of them were about conditional statements about the columns in database itself.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: what version of rails you are using,the query is correct & works for me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error relates to the constant User not being defined, however to answer your question about the where method...

```
:city_of_birth != :favourite_city
```

This will always be true, so your actually calling where like this...

```
User.where(true)
```

This won't do much I'm afraid. I think you maybe getting this confused with the hash condition syntax which can be used. That also won't be of much use to you. You would need to use a string condition like this...

```
User.where('users.city_of_birth != users. favourite_city')
```

This is effectively just a snippet of SQL that will eventually be included in the final statement sent to the database.

Answer (score 3):

This error is stating that `User` isn't defined -- either you have the wrong class name, or it's not being loaded into your environment.

Comment: Thank you. I'm almost certain that the error resides in the syntax `:city_of_birth != :favourite_city`. I am not sure how to accomplish comparison between two database columns.