# RoR Search conditions comparing two columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What I basically want to do is the following:

```
a = Assignment.all(:conditions => { :end_date < :start_date })
```

I only want to select those records on which the `end_date` is *before* the `start_date`.

I actually don't want ending up writing a
`for each`, push to array if `end_date` is earlier than `start_date`.

How can I achieve this in a pretty 'Railsy'-way?

Thank you in advance.

#### Edit:

I think the problem is comparing the values of both columns. (Allmost) every query is comparing a cell-value to an input-value.
This is a shot in the dark, but maybe one in the right direction ?

Haven't figured out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while here but nevertheless, you can just use the `ArelTable` method:

```
t = Assignment.arel_table
Assignment.where(t[:end_date].lt(t[:start_date]))
```

The condition predicates documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Predications

The `ArelTable` documentation: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/Table

And a good guide: http://jpospisil.com/2014/06/16/the-definitive-guide-to-arel-the-sql-manager-for-ruby.html

Answer (score 0):

```
a = Assignment.all(:conditions => ["end_date < ?", :start_date ])
```

Check this: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-all

I am assuming that you are using ActiveRecord

Comment: Thank you for your response. As far as I know, I indeed am using AR. I tried your possible solution, but I do get all data to be selected. I made sure both columns are Date objects.

Comment: try `a = Assignment.where(["end_date < ?", :start_date ])`

Comment: Thank you, still all data is selected somehow. The SQL query executed is: `Regioassignment Load (20.2ms)  SELECT "regioassignments".* FROM "regioassignments" WHERE (assignment_expected_end_date < 'assignment_start_date')`

Comment: Well, not too sure but try `a = Assignment.where(["end_date < ?", start_date ])`

Comment: Good one, but now I got the NameError: `undefined local variable or method `assignment_start_date' for main:Object`. So I think the `:` must be there.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
a = Assignment.where('regioassignments.end_date < regioassignments.start_date')
```

use the tablename followed by the EXACT COLUMNNAMES in the database, since ActiveRecord recognizes this and uses this as SQL directly.
That means the columnname for end_date is probably assignment_expected_end_date from what I figured from one of your comments.

adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615134/rails-3-activerecord-where-not-equal-condition-comparison-between-two-columns)